# problems with CountDownTimerWithPause

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I'm trying to use this timer, like on this question suggested:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806545/how-to-extend-countdown-timer-with-pause,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806545/how-to-extend-countdown-timer-with-pause)

but doesn't work as expected. The pause/resume works fine, but if I cancel and recreate the timer, then the counting starts from the last paused time. I need to start from the initial value.
For eg the counter's intial value is 3 minutes. If I paused it at 2 minutes, then when I'm trying to create it again it starts from 2 minutes.
Any help?

```
    public class MainActivity extends ButtonMethods implements OnClickListener {



    private CountDownTimerWithPause timerPausable = null;
    int milis = 180000;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

timerPausable = new CountDownTimerWithPause(milis, 1000, true)
{

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
                timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                timer.setText("180");
                DisableRandomButtons();
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bNewWord:

                if(clicked == false){
                    clicked = true;
                    timerPausable.create();             
                }
                else{
                    clicked = false;
                    timerPausable.cancel();
                    timerPausable=null;
                    milis=180000;
                    timerPausable.create();
            }
             break;
             case R.id.imageView2:
        tapsound.start();
        if(isclicked == false){
            isclicked = true;
            timerPausable.pause();
                   }
        else{
            isclicked = false;
        timerPausable.resume();
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say what your exact problem is without seeing your code but what I did was call `cancel()` on my timer then make it equal to `null` to reset it. Mine is a little different and I handle it in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    timer.cancel();          // timer is a reference to my inner CountDownTimer class
    timer = null;
    secs = 10;
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for. It works for me.

Comment: I added the code of button. I tried to use the null value(the secs variable what is?) but I get nullpointer exception. The above code works fine if I don't use the pause resume functions.

Comment: secs is my `millisInFuture` variable for the constructor, sorry

Comment: null keeps give null pointer exception, I'll add all references to timer.

Comment: Where are you getting the `NPE` at and when? Also, reset your time after you cancel your timer `milis = 180000;`

Comment: In onClick method, on create the timer again. And also I aready reseting it after cancel.

Comment: I updated the code with the way I'm doing it. The variable secs Is Integer or long?

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood what you were doing. This will definitely cause `NPE`. This works if you leave the `Activity` then come back but you can't call `create()` on it after setting it to `null`. If the `create()` method creates a new reference to it then you should just be able to reset the `millis` variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27332/discussion-between-dancer-69-and-codemagic)